# video share on FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

```
 if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"])
{

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rabbit" ofType:@"mp4"]]];

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos"
                                  parameters:@{@"source":videoData}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {

        if (result) {
            NSLog(@"video shared successfully !!!!!!!! %@",result);

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Error %@",error.description);

    }
                 // Handle the result
    }];
     }
```

i tried this code but its not working...can someone tell how to achieve video share on FBSDKGraphRequest.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "code not working"?

Comment: code is working but video is not sharing on facebook

Answer (score 0):

This is right code. First grant permission "publish_actions" from Facebook Review.

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Title Text", @"title",
                                   @"Desciption Text", @"description",
                                   nil];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                              parameters:params
                                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    [connection addRequest:request
         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {


             if (!error) {

                 NSLog(@"Video uploaded successfuly! %@",result);

             } else {

                 NSLog(@"Video uploaded failed :( %@",error.userInfo);

             }



         }];

    [connection start];
```

Comment: this code is depreceated in latest fbsdk.could you help in this

Comment: This is not deprecated. I have used just 3 days ago. This is latest from API V2.4

Comment: Have you granted publish_action permission from Facebook review ?

Comment: @SolidSoft, could you send a a link with a documentation where `contentType` and `video.mov` keys are described?

Comment: @lulian Have you marked this negative mark !! This is for your reference. http://righthelp.xyz/question/32263933/video-share-on-fbsdkgraphrequest

Comment: @SolidSoft, official documentation, like [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos) where it states that `the video, encoded as form data` has to be set for the key `source` which is __required__. The `contentType` key is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei your shared link does not contain post video info. It has, how to get user's video. Read it again.

Comment: @SolidSoft, It does, at the section named `Creation`

Comment: @IulianOnofrei  Then What's wrong in my code ? Why my code uploading video on FB wall ??

Comment: @SolidSoft, I couldn't find the dictionary keys used by you in any official documentation or sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logOut];

[loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                  handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                      if(error!=nil)
                                      {
     NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [params setObject:dataVideoCompress forKey:@"abc.mov"];
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" parameters:params tokenString:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString version:FBSDK_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                                           {
                                               if(error!=nil)
                                               {
                                               }
                                           }];
                                           }
}];
```